# Backbone View and template

Tags: backbone.js, view

How would I create a view and template from either this model or collection? I can console log the data I want. I'm stuck on the view and template part. Thanks.

```
var Weather = Backbone.Model.extend({
urlRoot: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=New%20York&mode=json&units=imperial",
initialize: function (response) {
        console.log(response.wind.speed);    
console.log(response.main.temp);     
 console.log(response.name);
 console.log(response.main.temp_min);
 console.log(response.main.temp_max);
 //console.log();
 return response;   
}

});

var WeatherCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
 model: Weather,
 url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=New%20York&mode=json&units=imperial',
 parse: function(response) {
        console.log(response.wind.speed);    
console.log(response.main.temp);     
 console.log(response.name);
 console.log(response.main.temp_min);
 console.log(response.main.temp_max);
 //console.log();
 return response;
 }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do something like this to start with:

```
var WeatherItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: _.template($('#weather-template').html()),
  render: function () {
    var content = this.template({
      weather: this.model
    });

    this.$el.html(content);
    return this;
  }
});

var WeatherListView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function () {
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sync', this.render);
  },
  render: function () {
    this.collection.each(function (weather) {
      var subView = new WeatherItemView({
        model: weather
      });
      this.$el.append(subView.render().$el);
    }, this);

    return this;
  }
});

$(document).ready(function () {
  var weathers = new WeatherCollection();
  weathers.fetch(); // assuming its accessing an api endpoint.

  var weathersView = new WeatherListView({
    collection: weathers
  });
  $('body').html(weathers.render().$el);
});

<!-- template for one weather item view -->
<script id='weather-template' type="text/template">
  <%= weather.escape('name') %>
</script>
```